# What is the Dog Shrine? Where can I find it?

Tags: achievements, undertale

Over half of [Undertale's PS4 trophies](https://psnprofiles.com/trophies/6487-undertale) ask the player to donate a specific amount of money to a Dog Shrine.

[image: Dognation Level 1 - Donate 2G to the Dog Shrine]

I don't remember there being any Dog Shrine when I played the game on PC.

What is the Dog Shrine? Where can I find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Dog Shrine is only available on the PS4. From [this article](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2017-08-18-undertale-trophies-list-dog-shrine-platinum-4873):

> The Dog Shrine is located in Papyrus's house at the back of the kitchen. Make sure you spare him during the story (which means you must not be playing as part of a Genocide run) and head inside.

Answer (score 0):

The Dog Shrine IS NOT in the PC version of the game.. sort of. In order to access it you need to have a hex editor like HxD and modify the data.win file of UNDERTALE. Here's a link to a guide that shows how to do it https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1118863642